Crop a huge bar plot to leave place for other bars in Python
With that code :
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Creating toy data
np.random.seed(0)
genera = ['Genus{}'.format(i) for i in range(1, 11)]
counts = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=len(genera))
counts[0] = 1000  # Adding a large count for demonstration
data = {'Genus': genera, 'Count': counts}
bacteria_df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Plotting the bar plot
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))  # Adjust the figure size as needed
plt.bar(bacteria_df['Genus'], bacteria_df['Count'], color='skyblue')
plt.xlabel('Genus')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Count of Bacteria Genera')
plt.xticks(rotation=45, ha='right')  # Rotate x-axis labels for better readability
plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust layout to prevent clipping of labels
plt.show()

I managed to create this plot :

But I am looking for a way to crop the huge bars in order to leave more space for the others bar to show details.
A such code should give something like that :


plt.yscale('log') is an alternative
